knife_project context
I am trying to get the knife project operation to work through python on Blender 4.2.
The following code does not work on when run on a new instance of blender. The script works when called the second time after the first run. I do not get any errors just the knife_project intersection fails to execute the first time.
import bpy
import os

area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
home_directory = os.path.expanduser("~")
file_path = home_directory + "/abc/"
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.ops.object.delete()

cutter_names = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
target_object_name = ["5", "6"]        

def import_stl(stlfiles):
    for files in stlfiles:
        bpy.ops.wm.stl_import(filepath = file_path + files + ".stl")
        
def export_stl(stlfile):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    target = bpy.data.objects[stlfile]
    target.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.wm.stl_export(filepath = file_path + target_object_name + "-cut.stl", export_selected_objects = True)
    
def cutter(target_object, cutter_names):
    areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]
    with bpy.context.temp_override(window=bpy.context.window,
                                    area=areas[0],
                                    region=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
                                    screen=bpy.context.window.screen):
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_axis(type='LEFT', align_active=True)
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_all(center=False)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  # Deselect all objects
        target = bpy.data.objects[target_object]
        projectors = [bpy.data.objects[name] for name in cutter_names]
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = target

        target.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

        # Perform Knife Project for each projector object
        for projector in projectors:
            projector.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(cut_through = True)
        
    #bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')
    
import_stl(cutter_names)
import_stl(target_object_name)
cutter("5", cutter_names)

Am I implementing the context correctly? Any help is appreciated.

Please use the python and/or scripting when asking Python questions! People can use tags for filtering questions here.

What do you mean by "fails to execute the first time"? Like the op runs but it does nothing to the mesh? The operator won't run at all?

@Jakemoyo The view is changed, but the knife_project() does nothing to the mesh. When I run the script again, the mesh intersection is successful. One more thing I have noticed is that if I change the view and run the script again, the intersection is done with the previous view in context. I have to run the script twice if I manually change the view in 3D.

Looks like the used ops.view3d are not updating the viewport before knife_project and do that only after the script exits.

@unwave If I run the script with the knife_project() commented out, I can see the viewport updating correctly. According to the documentation knife_project() does not run without with bpy.context.temp_override(). Is there a necessity to update the context before the knife_project ? How to do this?

I think the issue is that the ops.view3d are meant for modal viewport navigation. They have transition animations and are applied over a span of multiple frames, iterating through the main application loop. Therefore, it cannot be contained in a single python execution. You are better off editing the viewport camera manually and using something like camera_fit_coords.

@unwave Still the same issue when using camera_fit_coords. I am using it like this to update the camera.
location, scale = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, coordinates) camera.location = location
the camera toggle still uses bpy.ops.view3d.view_camera(). The view is required for knife project.

view3d_area.spaces.active.region_3d.update() needs to be called after updating the view with bpy.ops

Yeah, even region_3d.view_matrix = view_matrix does not change the region_3d.view_matrix before the script exits. Which is rather strange.

crash when running python in background mode and calling region_3d.update()

A variant that does not use ops.viwe3d.
import bpy
import mathutils
import math


def get_bound_box_coordiates(objects):
    coordinates = []

    for object in objects:
        matrix_world = object.matrix_world
        for v in object.bound_box:
            coordinates.extend(matrix_world @ mathutils.Vector(v))

    return coordinates


def get_coordiates(objects):
    coordinates = []

    for object in objects:
        matrix_world = object.matrix_world
        for vert in object.data.vertices:
            coordinates.extend(matrix_world @ vert.co)

    return coordinates


def get_view3d():
    for window_manager in bpy.data.window_managers:
        for window in window_manager.windows:
            for area in window.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    for region in area.regions:
                        if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                            return dict(window=window, workspace=window.workspace, screen=window.screen, area=area, region=region)

    raise Exception('View3D context not found.')

view3d_context = get_view3d()

camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
target = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]
projector = bpy.data.objects["Grid"]

projector_matrix = projector.matrix_world.copy()

camera.matrix_world = projector_matrix

coordinates = get_coordiates([projector])

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
location, ortho_scale = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, coordinates)
camera.location = location

view_matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale(location, projector_matrix.to_quaternion(), None).inverted_safe()

space_view = view3d_context['area'].spaces.active

space_view.region_3d.update()

prev_view_matrix = space_view.region_3d.view_matrix.copy()


space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = view_matrix
space_view.region_3d.update()


if bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

target.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = target
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

projector.select_set(True)

with bpy.context.temp_override(**view3d_context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(cut_through = True)


space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = prev_view_matrix


One that works in the background.
import bpy
import mathutils
import sys
import os


def get_coordinates(objects):
    coordinates = []

    for object in objects:
        matrix_world = object.matrix_world
        for vert in object.data.vertices:
            coordinates.extend(matrix_world @ vert.co)

    return coordinates


def get_view3d():
    for window_manager in bpy.data.window_managers:
        for window in window_manager.windows:
            for area in window.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    for region in area.regions:
                        if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                            return dict(window=window, workspace=window.workspace, screen=window.screen, area=area, region=region)

    raise Exception('View3D context not found.')

view3d_context = get_view3d()

camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
target = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]
projector = bpy.data.objects["Grid"]

projector_matrix = projector.matrix_world.copy()

camera.matrix_world = projector_matrix

coordinates = get_coordinates([projector])

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
location, ortho_scale = camera.camera_fit_coords(depsgraph, coordinates)
camera.location = location

space_view = view3d_context['area'].spaces.active

prev_view_matrix = space_view.region_3d.view_matrix.copy()

window_matrix: mathutils.Matrix = space_view.region_3d.window_matrix.copy()
view_matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale(location, projector_matrix.to_quaternion(), None).inverted_safe()


## update region 3D
if '--native' in sys.argv:
    space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = view_matrix
    space_view.region_3d.update()

elif '--none' in sys.argv:
    space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = view_matrix

else:
    import ctypes

    class Region_3D_Struct(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("winmat", (ctypes.c_float * 4) * 4),
            ("viewmat", (ctypes.c_float * 4) * 4),
            ("viewinv", (ctypes.c_float * 4) * 4),
            ("persmat", (ctypes.c_float * 4) * 4),
            ("persinv", (ctypes.c_float * 4) * 4),
        ]
        

    region_data = Region_3D_Struct.from_address(space_view.region_3d.as_pointer())


    matrix = view_matrix.transposed()
    for i in range(4):
        region_data.viewmat[i] = (ctypes.c_float * 4)(*matrix[i])


    matrix = view_matrix.inverted_safe().transposed()
    for i in range(4):
        region_data.viewinv[i] = (ctypes.c_float * 4)(*matrix[i])


    perspective_matrix = window_matrix @ view_matrix

    matrix = perspective_matrix.transposed()
    for i in range(4):
        region_data.persmat[i] = (ctypes.c_float * 4)(*matrix[i])

    matrix = perspective_matrix.inverted_safe().transposed()
    for i in range(4):
        region_data.persinv[i] = (ctypes.c_float * 4)(*matrix[i])


    space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = space_view.region_3d.view_matrix


## cut
if bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

target.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = target
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

projector.select_set(True)

with bpy.context.temp_override(**view3d_context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.knife_project(cut_through = True)


bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

space_view.region_3d.view_matrix = prev_view_matrix


path, ext = os.path.splitext(bpy.data.filepath)
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath=f"{path}_knife_result{ext}", copy=True)

C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\blender.exe" D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend --python-text "Text" -b --factory-startup -- --native
Blender 4.3.0 (hash 2b18cad88b13 built 2024-11-19 11:04:29)
Read blend: "D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend"
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF78463412F
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00003538
Writing: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\the_latest_test.crash.txt

C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\blender.exe" D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend --python-text "Text" -b --factory-startup -- --none
Blender 4.3.0 (hash 2b18cad88b13 built 2024-11-19 11:04:29)
Read blend: "D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend"
Info: Saved "the_latest_test_knife_result.blend"

Blender quit

C:\Users\user>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\blender.exe" D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend --python-text "Text" -b --factory-startup --
Blender 4.3.0 (hash 2b18cad88b13 built 2024-11-19 11:04:29)
Read blend: "D:\Desktop\the_latest_test.blend"
Info: Saved "the_latest_test_knife_result.blend"

Blender quit


